# datatables show double order icon on header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables-1.10

I'm creating a simple table using datatables with bootstrap with this instructions

```
var bTable = $('#example2').DataTable( {
        language: {  url: 'assets/plugins/datatables/i18n/Spanish.json'     },
        processing: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive:true,
        ajax: "modulos/estados.data.php",
        columns: [
            { data: "id561" },
            { data: "des561" },
            { data: "accion561" },
            { data: "res561" }
        ],
        order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets : 0,
                searchable: false,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) 
                { return row.id561 }
            },
            {
                targets : 1,
                searchable: true,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) 
                { return data }
            },
            {
                targets : 2,
                searchable: false,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) 
                { return data }
            },
            {
                targets : 3,
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) 
                { return data }
            }
        ]
    } );
```

The problem is that its show on header the order icon twice as shown on image
[image]

the problem is only activating Bootstrap css, if I use jquery its works

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you're not including DataTables CSS file (`jquery.dataTables.min.css`), only `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css`.

If you're using [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index), select **Bootstrap** in the **Styling** section. If you already have Bootstrap included, chose **No styling library**, otherwise chose **Include library** to include the latest Bootstrap as well.

See [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) for demonstration of correct usage.

Comment: This not correct the problem. The table element is  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example2">. The datatable package was build using Jquery 2.x+Bootstrap+some extensions

Comment: @MartinVarta, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rhjLbgyw/) of your issue, this is very common problem. The issue also occurs when you include `jquery.dataTables.min.css` in addition to other files as I mentioned in my answer. Please list the files that you include or remove `jquery.dataTables.min.css` and see if that corrects the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, .sorting_desc, .sorting {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this issue:
Commented the "content" from app.css

```
table.dataTable > thead .sorting:before,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_asc:before,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_desc:before,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  right: 1em;
  /* content: "↑"; */
}
table.dataTable > thead .sorting:after,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_desc:after,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after,
table.dataTable > thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after {
  right: 0.5em;
  /* content: "↓"; */
}
```

and included jquery.dataTables.min.css